# Symfony href shoud work for app_dev.php and app.php

Tags: php, symfony, href

I have in Twig an link:

link

Which outputs as url: www.domain.com/category-laptops

But on dev I need to output: www.domain.com/app_dev.php/category-laptops

Is there some function for this, or should I write by my own based on the environment?

Thanks
Nik

Comment: Don't hardcode links, use `{{ path('routename') }}`  in your twig

Comment: path() works only if there is a route for this URL. But when I have some link like: category-laptops and my router is: path:     /{catchall} this not works.

Comment: this is not best practice. you should have a route for every controller. Think about a route `category/{c}` with parameter `c` which is `laptops`

Comment: You could then use  `{{ path('routename', {'catchall': 'category-laptops'}) }}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `{{ path() }}` in your twig-template for that.

example:

```
<a href="{{ path('article_show', {'slug': article.slug}) }}">
    {{ article.title }}
</a>
```

See: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/twig_reference.html#path

If you want to use absolute links, you can use `{{ url() }}` instead of `{{ path() }}`

See: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/twig_reference.html#url

Comment: Ok it works great in this way! Thanks! Here my code: 
href="{{ path('catch_all', {'catchall': category.keyword_url}) }}"

Answer (score 1):

If you've set up the route correctly then `path('route_name')` should give you the correct link in both environments.